# Customize padding of \boxed environment in MathJax

Tags: mathjax

What is the most appropriate way of customizing the amount of padding that Mathjax produces for the `\boxed{}` envorinment? I know there is a `\bbox[]{}` alternative with such an option, but it is buggy for the CommonHTML output that I use (it excludes the punctuation symbols).

If it helps to answer the question, I am specifically using `page2html` from the mathjax-node package to pre-render all the math.

Comment: What problems do you see with `\bbox` using the CommonHTML output with mathjax-node?

Comment: I mention it in the question: bbox ignores a period symbol at the end of the equations.

Comment: Maybe report a bug with an example?

Comment: I agree, i will do it.